Ansible: Regex not working as expected for multiline string
I am working on an Ansible playbook for iOS flash files backup, which shows the flash: of a Cisco router and tries to pick all the filenames from the multiline string into a list. Later it will create a directory with the name of the host and dump every file iteratively.
---
- name: Backup Flash Files from Cisco Devices
  hosts: cisco
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: List flash files
      ios_command:
        commands:
          - "show flash:"
      register: flash_files

    - name: Debug flash files output
      debug:
        var: flash_files.stdout_lines 

    - name: Extract file names
      set_fact:
        files: "{{ flash_files.stdout_lines | select('search', '\\+00:00\\s+.*') | map('regex_replace', '^.*\\+00:00\\s+(.*)$', '\\1') | list }}"

    - name: Create directory on local
      delegate_to: localhost
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: "/ios_backup/{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        state: directory
 
    - name: Copy flash files to local
      fetch:
        src: "flash:{{ item }}"
        dest: "/ios_backup/{{ inventory_hostname }}/"
        flat: yes
      loop: "{{ files }}"

I can see flash_files.stdout_lines indeed contains everything I need, in a pattern
<serial number> <timestamp> 00:00 <filename>

However, the regex only finds the last file name out of it to variable files. Any suggestions what might go wrong?

Put the single-quoted regex into a variable. This simplifies the escaping. Split the lines and get the last elements
    files_regex: '\s+00:00\s+'
    files: "{{ flash_files.stdout_lines |
               select('search', files_regex) |
               map('split') |
               map('last') }}"



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    flash_files:
      stdout_lines:
        - foo
        - <serial number> <timestamp> 00:00 filename1
        - bar
        - <serial number> <timestamp> 00:00 filename2
        - <serial number> <timestamp> 00:00 filename3

    files_regex: '\s+00:00\s+'
    files: "{{ flash_files.stdout_lines |
               select('search', files_regex) |
               map('split') |
               map('last') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: files

gives
  files:
  - filename1
  - filename2
  - filename3


